# Let $\phi :F \to R $ be a ring homorphism. Prove either $\forall x \in F ,\phi (x)=0 $ or $\phi$ injective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi :F $ $\to$  $ R $ be a ring homorphism. Prove either $\forall x \in F ,\phi (x)=0 $ or $\phi$ injective.

---

Def homorphic: $\forall x,y \in F \Rightarrow f(a)+f(b)=f(a+b) \wedge f(a)f(b)=f(ab) $

Injective (one-to-one) If $f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$

---

My attempt

There are 2 cases either $\forall x \in F:\phi (x)=0$ or not that is $\exists x \in F:\phi (x)\neq 0$.

There is theorem stating that $f(0_S)=0_R$

*(Need to show that in the case $\exists x \in F:\phi (x)\neq 0$ $\implies$ injective)*

Assume $f(a)=f(b)\equiv f(a-b)=0_R=f(0_s)$ so $a-b=0_s$$\therefore$ $a=b$

---

Not sure it might be correct. Also, In the case that shows it is injective it is bothering me that the special property was not used. 
There is a related problem but it is a [field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36784/abstract-algebra-ring-homomorphism) So i think i can't make 
same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232955/how-to-prove-that-homomorphism-from-field-to-ring-is-injective-or-zero)

Comment: This is a duplicate of one of the linked questions. Was not obvious F was a field to me at the time. I just cannot say any ideal in $F$ is a simple since this is the first time I have heard it. So kernel is either $F$ or $\{0\}$. If kernel is $\{0\}$ there is a theorem I can use to say it is injective. and if the kernel is F then i can say everything is mapped to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have realized in your comment, this statement is true when $F$ is a field. Here is an example that the statement need not be true when $F$ is not a field -

Let $\phi:\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z_2$ be the map given by $\phi(n)=[n]$ where $[n]$ is the remainder when $n$ is divided by $2$. This is a ring homomorphism that is neither the zero homomorphism nor injective.