# Characterization of fields by injective homormorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ring-homomorphism

I am working on the converse of [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36784/ring-homomorphism-defined-on-a-field). Basically I want to close the characterization as:

> Given a commutative ring $R$ with unit. 
>   If every non trivial
>   homomorphism from $R$ is a monomorphism then $R$ is a field.

I think it has to be simple but I don't see a clear manner to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware, your characterization is only true for commutative rings with units.

Suppose $R$ is not a field. Then it has an ideal $I$ which is not $(0)$ nor $R$. Just check that $\pi : R \rightarrow R/I$ is not a monomorphism and $\pi$ is not trivial to prove your result.